# Is there a pure CSS way to detect whether the text has wrapped and give it different styles?

Tags: html, css

For example, I have a button with a long text on it:

[Please click this button for more information]

Since the text is very long, on some small screens, it would be wrapped.

[Please click this button for
more information]

I want to make the `text-align` as `left` when it's wrapped and `center` when it's not.

For instance:

[image: wrapped text at normal size]

[image: text in a single line at a smaller size]

Is there any pure CSS solution for it?

Comment: Media queries are probably the best way to handle this

Comment: Its realy short, so i just put it here :  @media(max-width: 650px) { .button { text-align: center} }  . Just adjust the targeted max-width you want the button to response to.

Comment: pure css.... no

Answer (score 1):

There is no *general* way to apply different styles to elements at different widths using only CSS. This is a very good thing because it could be very easily broken, as the following example shows (using pseudocode with the form of CSS media queries).

```
@element( min-width: 600px ) {
    button {
        width: 500px;
    }
}
@element( max-width: 600px ) {
    button {
        width: 700px;
    }
}
```

### CSS

The only way to do it using pure CSS is to find the window width at which the button text is rendered over two lines, and write a media query for that width. For example, if you test your page and find that when it is sized at 500px width or less the button is squished so that the text renders on two lines, you might add the style:

```
.button {
    text-align: center;
}
@media( max-width: 500px ) {
    .button {
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

Of course, the exact point at which the text is rendered over two lines may differ depending on browser/layout engine.

### JavaScript

Using JavaScript you can test the height of each button when the page loads and when the page is resized. If you know the height of the button when it has a single line of text and the button's height is greater than that, then you can apply a different style to those buttons.

For example:

```js
function buttonStyles() {
  let buttons = document.querySelectorAll( 'button' )
  for ( let button of buttons ) {
    if ( button.offsetHeight > 40 ) {
      button.classList.add( 'left' )
    } else {
      button.classList.remove( 'left' )
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener( 'load', buttonStyles )
window.addEventListener( 'resize', buttonStyles )
```

```css
button {
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
}
button.left {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<button>A single line</button>

<button>Two<br>lines</button>
```

Comment: if you have to use JavaScript, is there a way to do so? Thanks

Comment: @AGamePlayer you can calculate the height of the text and determine if there's a line break, but IMO that's much more work than it's worth.

Comment: @AGamePlayer updated answer with JavaScript solution